# Invoke default phase on maven plugin execution

Tags: maven, maven-3, integration-testing, maven-plugin

Edit: All I want to do is call a maven default phase(this case its process-classes) in a maven plugin(in this case failsafe plugin)

Edit2: made the title more clear, editted the description

Good day,

After exhausting myself on doing this, I have no option but to ask a question.

Basically this run my integration-test fine.

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests
mvn verify
```

this works well. I just need a way to configure the first two commands to execute on pre-integration-test so that when the user enters mvn verify, the first two commands are executed automagically:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>clean-package</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>mvn</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>clean</argument>
                            <arguments>package</arguments>
                              <arguments>-Dmaven.test.skip</arguments>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I cant seem to find what plugin in maven that executes the said phases.

can you point me to the right direction? I would appreciate if the answer will be explained(I shall read the documentation thoroughly)

Thanks!

Comment: First you have written that your integration tests were runnging but than asking how to do this with mave-failsafe-plugin? You have mentioned things which have no relationship to integration tests nor maven-failsafe-plugin can you pleasae eleborate more what exactly you did already and what you like to achieve and what does not work as you expect it work.

Comment: what I just need to do is package the bundle before running the integration tests :). I use pax exam for integration test, however that is irrelevant for now.

This is also for future reference of how to invoke maven default goal on certain plugins

TLDR; call process-classes on pre-integration-test phase.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly you would like to execute `mvn clean package -DskipTests` automatically if some calls `mvn verify`? Is this correct?

The first thing is `package` is a [life cycle phase](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference). The `verify` in your second call is also an life cycle phase.

The life cycle in Maven is the way that if you `mvn verify` all phases

```
validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, 
process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, 
process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, 
test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, 
pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify
```

running one after an other which means the `package` phase is included.

If you really like to ingnore the unit tests via `-DskipTests` you could simply do that by:

```
mvn -DskipTests verify
```

which i can't recommend.

As you mentioned your artifacts is a bundle it should be packaged during the `package` phase and you can run your integration tests on it afterwards in the life-cycle.

Answer (score 0):

How about using exec-maven-plugin [1]

Example:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>clean-process-classes</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <executable>maven</executable>
              <arguments>
                <argument>clean</argument>
                <argument>process-classes</argument>
              </arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>felix-bundle</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <executable>maven</executable>
              <arguments>
                <argument>org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:bundle</argument>
                <argument>-DskipTests</argument>
              </arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
   ...
</project>
```

Note: Untested code.
Note2: Technically 'process-classes' is not a maven goal. It is a maven phase. Goals attach themselves to maven phases so that when that phase gets executed, it will execute all goals attached to that phase and all goals attached to phases prior to that. In Maven, goals have a format of something like [groupId:]artifactId:[version:]goal. A good indicator is that if you see a colon, it's a maven goal. If it's prefixed by a '-' or '--', it's an option. Otherwise, it's a maven phase. See [2] for more info on the maven lifecycle.

[1] http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html

[2] http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Comment: tried doing it via the editted config above and does not work.